# Regular Expression for Skipping splits in java

Tags: java, regex

Let's say i have a line that looks like this

```
40  ,O12,O23,O34,O2
```

There's tab between the `40` and comma `,`.

I need a regular expression that outputs

```
O12,O23,O34,O2
```

as one `String`.

```
line.splits(",") // will splits commas , but how to skip the first which is 40 in the sentence ??
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: One easy solution is simply not using the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just match all the characters from the start upto the tab character plus the following `,`. REplacing the matched chars with empty string will give you the desired output.

```
String text = "40\t,O12,O23,O34,O2";
System.out.println(text.replaceFirst(".*\t,", ""));
```

OR

```
String text = "40\t,O12,O23,O34,O2";
System.out.println(text.replaceAll("^.*\t,", ""));
```

OR

```
String text = "40\t,O12,O23,O34,O2";
System.out.println(text.replaceAll("^.*?\t,", ""));
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't use regex. Just find the first occurrence of `"\t,"` and substring the original `String` from the end of that occurrence.

```
String text = "40\t,O12,O23,O34,O2";
System.out.println(text.substring(text.indexOf("\t,") + 2));
```

Answer (score 1):

The indexOf method returns the index at the first comma in the string. The 1 is added to start the substring past the comma.

```
line.substring(a.indexOf(",")+1);
```